# How to display a value (For eg: 0005-02-888888, 0005-02-888889) in a dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

In my database table, there is a field Acc.No of varchar type and its value is `0005-02-888888, 0005-02-888889, 0005-03-888889, 0002-03-888889`   I want to split and display it one by one in a dropdownlist. How can i do it? I am using VS2008 Asp.net 3.5 Framework c# with Sql Server 2005. I am a beginner, Any help will be appretiated.
Regards,

Comment: So you want 3 dropdown boxes, like 0005 then 02 then 888888 ?

Comment: @TomTom....No....i need 1 dropdownlist first item should be 005-02-888888 then the second one is 0005-02-888889 and so on...

Comment: what steps do you need help with? getting the data from the db? splitting the data using C#? populating the dropdown?

Comment: if you have already retrieved the data as a string then you are set with the answers below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a string array from the data string just go

```
string[] data = accNos.Split(',');
```

You might want to clean up your array values (e.g. any leading spaces):

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    data[i] = data[i].Trim();
}
```

Then bind your data to your dropdown list

```
cmbAccounts.DataSource = data;
cmbAccounts.DataBind();
```

Or, if you are using a BindingSource

```
bindingSource.DataSource = data;
bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
```

Comment: @tomfanning...I am getting this error. Error 137 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'. My code is  string[] splitString = myString;

Answer (score 1):

You can also split and trim in one line:

```
List<string> data = accNos.Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();
```

And of course you can bind in one line as well, if you prefer.

```
bindingSource.DataSource = accNos.Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();
```

Comment: Of course you need include a using System.Linq; at the top of your page.